# navigation.navigate does not change scene

Tags: node.js, react-native

I've been trying to work with this since yesterday, tried different methods and none actually worked. I'm currently using a drawer navigator, tab navigator and I want to open a different scene when clicking a icon.

Here is the current design:

[image]

The icon I want to open a new scene is the "filter" up on the top-right corner.
My current header code is:

```
<Header>
    <Left>
        <Icon name='ios-menu' style={{ color: 'white' }} onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())} />
    </Left>
    <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7 }}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTextTop}>Estabelecimentos</Text>
    </View>
    <Right>
        <Icon name='ios-search' style={{ paddingRight: 20, color: 'white' }} />
        <Icon name='ios-options' style={{ color: 'white' }} onPress={this.openFilter} />
    </Right>
</Header>
```

and here is the function openFilter:

```
openFilter = () =>
{
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Filter');
}
```

I'm importing the filter component from its .js file, I can't get it to switch scenes.

Here is the Filter.js (which i'm importing as import Filter from './Filter'):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import { Icon, Header, Left, Right } from 'native-base'

class Filter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Icon name='ios-arrow-back' style={{color: 'white'}} onPress={() =>
                            this.props.navigation.goBack()} />
                    </Left>
                    <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.7 }}>
                        <Text style={sty.headerTextTop}>Filtro</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Right>
                    </Right>
                </Header>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Filter;
```

--EDIT:--
As @Pritish Vaidya suggested, I should implement a Stack Navigator, so I made one:

```
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Filter from './Filter';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home';

const stackNav = StackNavigator({
    App: {
        screen: App,
        navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
            title: "Main",
            headerStyle: { paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }
        })
    },
    Filter: {
        screen: Filter,
        navigationOptions: (props) => ({
            title: "Filtro",
        })
    },
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: (props) => ({
            title: "Home",
        })
    }
})

export default stackNav;
```

But in Home.js when I call navigate using:

```
<Icon name='ios-options' style={{ color: 'white' }} onPress={() => this.props.navigator.navigate("Filter")} />
```

It gets me this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you also post your navigation stack, where the routes are defined?

Comment: For which navigation? Drawer or tabBar

Comment: Where you might have registered the FilterScreen, you need to register the FilterScreen to the navigation stack in order to navigate to it.

Comment: How do I do it? I have a const AppTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({ for the tab nav, bottom one. And const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({ for my drawer, I need another one?

Comment: Based on your current app , you would need a structure such as [this](https://codeburst.io/react-native-navigation-stack-navigator-inside-tab-navigator-inside-drawer-navigator-b2f21836708d), inside the `StackNavigator`, the `FilterScreen` would be defined.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I've tried implementing it and got an error, I updated the question with new information, please check it out

Comment: Try `this.props.navigation.navigate` , instead of `this.props.navigator.navigate`

Comment: When I click it nothing happens, Is like the stackNav is not really working, do I have to import it somewhere?

Comment: Just make sure that you include the `StackNavigator` to the parent navigator that you export and use in your App level component as defined in the tutorial I mentioned before, the rest should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177757/discussion-between-guilherme-garcia-da-rosa-and-pritish-vaidya).